# Orchard Projection Isotope

Tags: orchardcms, jquery-isotope

I'm trying create an affiliate directory on my Orchard site. The directory is populated by running a query on my custom Content Type. The directory needs to be sortable and searchable. I've set up a basic jsfiddle here that is a basic functioning version of what I'm attempting to do, but it's just in html: http://orchard1.pha.jhu.edu/affiliates-beta-2

```
Or you can view the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tgelles/AMZf8/
```

Has anyone discovered a way to best use isotope on an Orchard Projection? I've downloaded the Projection Layout module, but I have no idea how to use that/where to inject the specific isotope code. I've also created alternate template files for the Projection's Summary display, but I don't know how to best inject the isotope plugin into that razor file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be creating a shape, but You could easily edit the query template and inject the js through a custom view for that projection(url,type, etc)
Check in your Queries.
There was a video which helped me understand better how they work: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ka55wTTXZg8

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ErMasca. Unfortunately I don't know enough Razor to crate my own shape, but I did edit the query template through a custom view.  

However, I've discovered that when I add any tokens (e.g. "TaxonomyField.Terms[:*]} or {TaxonomyField.Terms} or {Content.Fields.Affiliate.Interest}) to the item class via the admin, they are not getting called. Yet if I enter their static value, they do get filtered. But I need several filter classes, not just one; which is why I am reliant on the tokens. It seems it's an issue Orchard is aware of, but wont bother alleviate

Comment: There was a post from some guy about that. We he fixed the chain for multiple taxomony terms. Worth having a look.
Additionally, you can create your own shape through c# code too. check this video from the last Orchard harvest http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKLjtCIs4G.

Comment: I'll look for that post, but FWIW I did manage to get the isotope to work--you have to have Properties as your Display Mode; add a new property; choose to Rewrite Results and then Output; place particular isotope div there. Thanks for the link; but seems to be dead! What was the name of the video?

Comment: There are all on the Orchard YouTube Channel : http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcEaR8HfGpPwt-GqJr_h5UQ